# Autodesk DWG Trueview Installation Arguments

Tags: windows-10, deployment, autocad, sccm, dwg

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask about applications so please let me know which one to post on for this if not.

My question is about Autodesk DWG Trueview. Can someone advise where I can find the documentation on the command line arguments for installing it on Windows 10 clients? I want to deploy silently through SCCM and enforce a restart. The silent install part is fine, but I want to avoid the part where it disables explorer which I believe is not done when a restart is specified.

Can anyone let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a MSI installer?
If so, you can use the default MSIEXEC arguments
/q for quiet install
/forcerestart for enforcing restart
REBOOT=ReallySuppress  or  /norestart  for suppressing reboot